# What is <HISTORY-LABEL> in stellar-core new-hist command?

Tags: stellar-core, history

The Error:

```
Nov 05 08:47:34 ip-10-31-37-117 stellar-core[8828]: cp: cannot stat '/var/www-host/stellar-core/history-cache/history/01/96/91/history-0196913f.json': No such file or directory
Nov 05 08:47:34 ip-10-31-37-117 stellar-core[8828]: 2019-11-05T08:47:34.170 GDPUZ [Process WARNING] process 8939 exited 1: cp /var/www-host/stellar-core/history-cache/history/01/96/91/history-0196913f.json /var/www-host/stellar-core/buckets/tmp/history-6ebd4a8a39fecd53/stellar-history.json
Nov 05 08:47:36 ip-10-31-37-117 stellar-core[8828]: cp: cannot stat '/var/www-host/stellar-core/history-cache/history/01/96/91/history-0196913f.json': No such file or directory
Nov 05 08:47:36 ip-10-31-37-117 stellar-core[8828]: 2019-11-05T08:47:36.171 GDPUZ [Process WARNING] process 8940 exited 1: cp /var/www-host/stellar-core/history-cache/history/01/96/91/history-0196913f.json /var/www-host/stellar-core/buckets/tmp/history-6ebd4a8a39fecd53/stellar-history.json
```

Does anyone know what value of `HISTORY-LABEL` is?

I enter `$ stellar-core new-hist sdf_watcher1 --conf stellar-core.cfg` then got error the following:

```
[History FATAL] Can't initialize unknown history archive 'sdf_watcher1' [HistoryArchiveManager.cpp:165]
```

```
2019-11-05T08:26:50.122 <startup> [default INFO] Config from stellar-core.cfg
2019-11-05T08:26:50.124 <startup> [default INFO] Using QUORUM_SET: {
   "t" : 4,
   "v" : [ "sdf_watcher1", "eno", "tempo.eu.com", "sdf_watcher2", "sdf_watcher3" ]
}

2019-11-05T08:26:50.124 <startup> [default INFO] Assigning calculated value of 1 to FAILURE_SAFETY

2019-11-05T08:26:50.168 GDPUZ [Database INFO] DB schema is in current version
2019-11-05T08:26:50.170 GDPUZ [History FATAL] Can't initialize unknown history archive 'sdf_watcher1' [HistoryArchiveManager.cpp:165]
2019-11-05T08:26:50.170 GDPUZ [default INFO] Application destructing
2019-11-05T08:26:50.171 GDPUZ [default INFO] Application destroyed
```

If I enter `$ stellar-core new-hist`, the following is `HISTORY-LABEL` argument is required

```
initialize history archives

usage:
  stellar-core new-hist <HISTORY-LABEL> ...  options

where options are:
  -?, -h, --help            display usage information
  --ll <LEVEL>              set the log level
  --metric <METRIC-NAME>    report metric METRIC-NAME on exit
  --conf <FILE-NAME>        specify a config file ('-' for STDIN, default
                            'stellar-core.cfg')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HISTORY-LABEL` in your case is the local history archive name (for example, `local`). You need to define it in your `stellar-core.cfg` first (check config example here: https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/docs/stellar-core_example.cfg#L479). And then initialize using `stellar-core new-hist local` command.

I'd recommend to start with reading the [administration docs](https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/software/admin.html) because you might not need the local archive in your case. It's optional and depends on your setup.